# Sorting a List of Objects which further has object in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, sorting, gridview

I have a List of Objects which further has objects 
For Eg.

```
Class Customer{
    string name;
    Address addr;
}

Class Address
{
    string city;
    string state;
}
```

Now i have a list of Customer objects which is bound to a gridview.

```
| Name | city | State |
```

I want to sort the gridview columns based on city and state.
How will i do it.

I tried doing

```
var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Customer), e.SortExpression);
var sortExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<Customer, object>>(
    Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(param, e.SortExpression),typeof(object)), param);
```

but when the sort expression is city, It does not sort.

Comment: You want to sort it before binding to GridView? Why you just don't use list.OrderBy(c => c.City)?

Comment: I want to sort it on the gridview sort event

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my sample that is working:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var list = new List<Customer>();

        list.Add(new Customer()
        {
            FirstName = "ztest",
            LastName = "ztest1",
            Address = new Address()
            {
                City = "Kiev"
            }
        });
        list.Add(new Customer()
        {
            FirstName = "test",
            LastName = "test1",
            Address = new Address()
            {
                City = "New York"
            }
        });


        string sortExpressionField = "Address.City";


        var props = sortExpressionField.Split('.');
        var inParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Customer));
        var param = props.Aggregate<string, Expression>(inParam, Expression.Property);
        var sortExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<Customer, object>>(param, inParam);

        var sorted = list.AsQueryable<Customer>().OrderBy(sortExpression);
        foreach (var item in sorted)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", item.FirstName, item.LastName);
        }
    }

}

public class Customer
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

Here is link to verify that it works - http://dotnetfiddle.net/iQSTBR

**UPDATE1**

For complex cases you need to parse properties, and navigate to the last property. I've updated code and here is example that works with sub properties - http://dotnetfiddle.net/alTWPK

**UPDATE2**

```
 var selectedNew = selected
       .AsQueryable<Customer>()
       .OrderBy(sortExpression)
       .ToList();
 gdvEmployees.DataSource = selectedNew; 
 gdvEmployees.DataBind();
```

Comment: It works fine when the sort expression is a member of class but it does not work when the sort expression is a member of member of class.   I mean when the class further has an object of another class and i am  sorting on that member. just like the city field of address class.

Comment: One more question. Now if i bind this "var sorted" to gridview which has paging enabled it it says **"the datasource does not support server side paging"** Can you help me out with that

Comment: You can try to call sorted.ToList(), that will get all items and convert them to usual List<T>.

Comment: var selectedNew = selected.AsQueryable<Customer>().OrderBy(sortExpression);  selectedNew.ToList<Customer>();  gdvEmployees.DataSource = selectedNew;  gdvEmployees.DataBind();  still giving same issue

Comment: It won't work. When you call ToList it will return new List item. And then you should save it in some variable and then use it. I've updated answer with sample of usage based on your code